# How to convert Burp Suite request body to python object?

Tags: python, http, request, burp

While testing one application I have needed to convert Burp Suite request body to python script. Here is body:

```
POST /api/w/e HTTP/2
Host: host.io
Cookie: LOCALE=en;
Content-Length: 1062
Sec-Ch-Ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="96"
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type: application/json
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: "macOS"
Origin: https://host.io
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: https://host.io/account
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8

{"data": "data"}
```

I was trying to convert that body to script like this:

```py
import requests

URL = "https://host.io/api/w/e"

dataObj = {"data": "data"}

headersObj = {
    "Host": "host.io",
    "Cookie": "LOCALE=en;",
    "Content-Length": "1062",
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "Sec-Ch-Ua": '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="96"',
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile": "?0",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36",
    "Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform": "macOS",
    "Origin": "https://host.io",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
    "Referer": "https://host.io/account",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
}

r = requests.post(url=URL, data=dataObj, headers=headersObj)
print(r)
```

Also I was trying to send cookies as object in request like `cookies=cookiesObj`, but no matter how I try every time I get 400 or JSON from server - `{status: 500, message: "something-went-wrong"}`. Why it doesn't work? Do I miss something important?

Comment: You need an API Access Token

Comment: Okey, but how should I put this token in body?

Comment: You'll need to check the API documentation